How to change Apple Account password on web when Stolen Device Protection is on and my only Apple device is stolen?
My device is fine for now. However, I do notice that, if I log in to account.apple.com using 2FA (password + device authentication code), I cannot change certain information, like to update Apple Account primary email, to remove a trusted device, and to change my password.
Warning message is as follows:

Because Stolen Device Protection is turned on, some of your account information can’t be changed on the web.

There was a similar post on Reddit several months back but I did not get a clear answer from there.
Focus on this question: If my only Apple device is my iPhone, and it is stolen, how am I supposed to change my Apple Account password?
The rest part of the original question is more of a complain than actual questions:

How is Stolen Device Protection protecting me in this way? Also if the thief has glimpsed and saw me entering my screen lock passcode, it might still be possible for them to change my Apple Account password just after a few more hours? I feel like now the life is easier for the thieve than it is for me.


The full message instructs to use one of your other Apple devices, but if you only have an iPhone this won't work. You may want to reach out to Apple Support for this.
